# For each Loop Not Print Proper Data

Tags: magento2, collection, product-collection

On product listing page I have `$_productCollection = $block->getLoadedProductCollection();` if I call getData on $_productCollection I get different array than I get in foreach loop. Does anyone have any idea about this.

Before foreach loop data looks like

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [row_id] => 1026
            [entity_id] => 1026
            [created_in] => 1
            [updated_in] => 2147483647
            [attribute_set_id] => 4
            [type_id] => simple
            [sku] => 47-62-532-11
            [has_options] => 0
            [required_options] => 0
            [created_at] => 2015-08-08 21:43:58
            [updated_at] => 2020-05-11 17:37:25
            [pim_updated_at] => 2019-11-02 22:29:43
            [status] => 1
            [price] => 3.5700
            [tax_class_id] => 5
            [final_price] => 3.5700
            [minimal_price] => 3.5700
            [min_price] => 3.5700
            [max_price] => 3.5700
            [tier_price] => 
            [most_view] => 9
            [is_salable] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [row_id] => 1028
            [entity_id] => 1028
            [created_in] => 1
            [updated_in] => 2147483647
            [attribute_set_id] => 4
            [type_id] => simple
            [sku] => 47-62-534-10
            [has_options] => 0
            [required_options] => 0
            [created_at] => 2015-08-08 21:44:08
            [updated_at] => 2020-05-11 05:18:23
            [pim_updated_at] => 2019-11-02 22:29:43
            [status] => 1
            [price] => 3.5700
            [tax_class_id] => 5
            [final_price] => 3.5700
            [minimal_price] => 3.5700
            [min_price] => 3.5700
            [max_price] => 3.5700
            [tier_price] => 
            [most_view] => 1
            [is_salable] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [row_id] => 1027
            [entity_id] => 1027
            [created_in] => 1
            [updated_in] => 2147483647
            [attribute_set_id] => 4
            [type_id] => simple
            [sku] => 47-62-532-14
            [has_options] => 0
            [required_options] => 0
            [created_at] => 2015-08-08 09:44:03
            [updated_at] => 2020-05-11 06:42:05
            [pim_updated_at] => 2019-11-02 22:29:43
            [status] => 1
            [price] => 3.4400
            [tax_class_id] => 5
            [final_price] => 3.4400
            [minimal_price] => 3.4400
            [min_price] => 3.4400
            [max_price] => 3.4400
            [tier_price] => 
            [most_view] => 1
            [is_salable] => 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [row_id] => 1025
            [entity_id] => 1025
            [created_in] => 1
            [updated_in] => 2147483647
            [attribute_set_id] => 4
            [type_id] => simple
            [sku] => 47-62-532-10
            [has_options] => 0
            [required_options] => 0
            [created_at] => 2015-08-08 13:43:53
            [updated_at] => 2020-05-11 06:11:17
            [pim_updated_at] => 2019-11-02 22:29:43
            [status] => 1
            [price] => 3.5700
            [tax_class_id] => 5
            [final_price] => 3.5700
            [minimal_price] => 3.5700
            [min_price] => 3.5700
            [max_price] => 3.5700
            [tier_price] => 
            [most_view] => 1
            [is_salable] => 1
        )

)
```

So, inside for each first product should be '47-62-532-11' but I am getting '47-62-534-10' SKU as the first element.

Answer (score 0):

When calling `getData()` you will call`\Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb::getData` and this is how it looks:

```php
/**
 * Get all data array for collection
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function getData()
{
    if ($this->_data === null) {
        $this->_renderFilters()->_renderOrders()->_renderLimit();
        $select = $this->getSelect();
        $this->_data = $this->_fetchAll($select);
        $this->_afterLoadData();
    }
    return $this->_data;
}
```

It will set filters, order and limit. Then fetch the data based on the current select.

When you foreach through the collection it will use `\Magento\Framework\Data\Collection::getIterator` which will create an `\ArrayIterator based on`$_items`.

So you use two different properties of the collection and they might be sorted differently. If you want the same data as in the foreach you can use `$_productCollection->getItems()` which will return `$_items`.